# LibGDX 1920x1080 resolution Television not fullscreen

Tags: java, libgdx, desktop

so I'm trying to make my application run fullscreen on all devices (for desktop), and when I run what I have on my laptop (1920x1080) fullscreen works fine. However when I run it on my Television, which is also (1920x1080), it doesn't take up the full screen but rather sits in the top left corner taking up most of the screen, leaving the windows behind it still visible on the right and bottom of the screen. My DektopLauncher looks as follows:

```
config.vSyncEnabled = false;
    config.width = LwjglApplicationConfiguration.getDesktopDisplayMode().width;
    config.height = LwjglApplicationConfiguration.getDesktopDisplayMode().height;
    config.useHDPI = true;
    config.fullscreen = true;
```

As you can see, I'm getting the resolution of the device, and using the fullscreen tag, but still no dice. Any suggestions would be great. Thanks :)

Comment: Give the lwjgl3 backend a try, see http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3870

Comment: Why don't you fix your size and let viewports handle the rest? Like `ExtendViewport` would extend your gameworld to the device and `FitViewport` would make it the same on every device and leaves a black bar to maintain aspect ratio.

You can always add a options screen where you can let the player choose the render resolution himself.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I am already using a StretchViewport to make the game take up the full screen. This works fine on almost all Android devices I've seen. The problem arises when I try to play the game on fullscreen desktop with a different resolution. It doesn't stretch to the full screen dimensions and sits in the top left of the screen. :/